# Networkx analysis

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have been working on the network analysis with Networkx. Could you please tell me where can I find tutorials or examples of network analysis of political networks (such as political parties or political bodies or political organizations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on what you actually need. I find youtube tutorials surprisingly helpful as starters, for example check this out here [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pT0IUOkOcGg), or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ErL1z_lKd8).

Personally I love MOOC courses! For example this one teaches you [Network Analysis in Pythons Networkx](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-social-network-analysis)

Hope this helps.